# How to remove .html extension using AWS Lambda & Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-serverless, aws-lambda-edge

1. I've my website's source code stored in AWS S3 and I'm using AWS Cloudfront to deliver my content.
2. I want to use AWS Lamda@Edge to remove .html extension from all the web links that's served through Cloudfront.
3. My required output should be www.example.com/foo instead of www.example.com/foo.html or example.com/foo1 instead of example.com/foo1.html.

Please help me to implement this as I can't find clear solution to use. I've referred the point 3 mentioned on this article: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=796961&tstart=0. But it's not clear what I need to do.

PFB the lambda code, how can I modify it-

```
const config = {
    suffix: '.html',
    appendToDirs: 'index.html',
    removeTrailingSlash: false,
};

const regexSuffixless = /\/[^/.]+$/; // e.g. "/some/page" but not "/", "/some/" or "/some.jpg"
const regexTrailingSlash = /.+\/$/; // e.g. "/some/" or "/some/page/" but not root "/"

exports.handler = function handler(event, context, callback) {
    const { request } = event.Records[0].cf;
    const { uri } = request;
    const { suffix, appendToDirs, removeTrailingSlash } = config;

    // Append ".html" to origin request
    if (suffix && uri.match(regexSuffixless)) {
        request.uri = uri + suffix;
        callback(null, request);
        return;
    }

    // Append "index.html" to origin request
    if (appendToDirs && uri.match(regexTrailingSlash)) {
        request.uri = uri + appendToDirs;
        callback(null, request);
        return;
    }

    // Redirect (301) non-root requests ending in "/" to URI without trailing slash
    if (removeTrailingSlash && uri.match(/.+\/$/)) {
        const response = {
            // body: '',
            // bodyEncoding: 'text',
            headers: {
                'location': [{
                    key: 'Location',
                    value: uri.slice(0, -1)
                 }]
            },
            status: '301',
            statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently'
        };
        callback(null, response);
        return;
    }

    // If nothing matches, return request unchanged
    callback(null, request);
};
```

Please help me to remove .html extension from my website and what updated code do I need to paste in my AWS Lambda
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: check might help you- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

Comment: I need to use AWS Lamda@Edge to remove the .html extension

Comment: check this  - https://github.com/riboseinc/terraform-aws-s3-cloudfront-website/issues/1

Comment: Can you please provide the lamda code which I can use for this purpose

Comment: share your lambda code here.

Comment: I've updated it in my question

Comment: Please help. Still looking for an answer